# How to override delete logic on Flask Admin?

Tags: python, flask-admin

I have been searching on Google and StackOverflow about this. Basically, I want to try and override the delete function on Flask-Admin to not actually delete a record, but instead update a row of the object called 'deleted_by' and 'deleted_on'.

I have found a few questions on StackOverflow that explain how to change the logic on the save button by using on_model_change, but no one specific about the delete model logic. I have also not found any information regarding this on the documentation. Could anyone show me how should I handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override method [`delete_model`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.delete_model) in your view. Here is the [default behaviour](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/8341a9ceae6e9206cb6b91a3b896ed02faaafccc/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L1172) if you are using Sqlalchemy views, note the call to `self.session.delete(model)` in the `try ... except` block.

```
def delete_model(self, model):
    """
        Delete model.
        :param model:
            Model to delete
    """
    try:
        self.on_model_delete(model)
        self.session.flush()
        self.session.delete(model)
        self.session.commit()
    except Exception as ex:
        if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
            flash(gettext('Failed to delete record. %(error)s', error=str(ex)), 'error')
            log.exception('Failed to delete record.')

        self.session.rollback()

        return False
    else:
        self.after_model_delete(model)

    return True
```

You would need something like the following in your view:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):


   def delete_model(self, model):
        """
            Delete model.
            :param model:
                Model to delete
        """
        try:
            self.on_model_delete(model)
            # Add your custom logic here and don't forget to commit any changes e.g. 
            # self.session.commit()
        except Exception as ex:
            if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
                flash(gettext('Failed to delete record. %(error)s', error=str(ex)), 'error')
                log.exception('Failed to delete record.')

            self.session.rollback()

            return False
        else:
            self.after_model_delete(model)

        return True
```

Also, you might not want to bother with the `self.on_model_delete(model)` and `self.after_model_delete(model)` calls because by default they do nothing.